# How to plot bar with different height and differenth width in matlab?

Tags: matlab, variables, graph, plot, width

I am having a big problem in Matlab, because it seems that I want to do something that is not so usual.

Basically I am trying to implement a way of group distribution together called Vincentizing.In order to do that I am following the instruction of a paper (*Ratcliff 1979 - Group Reaction Time Distributions and an Analysis of Distribution Statistics*).  Everything is fine until I have to plot the actual graph. I have an array that contains the quantiles of my dataset. The tutorial I am following says:

distribution histograms can be constructed by plotting quantiles on the abscissa and then constructing rectangles between adjacent quantiles such that all the rectangles have equal areas, as in Figure 2 (link of the image below)

http://postimg.org/image/btftrd6y7/

Once I calculate the quantiles, I can set the area to some value, let's say 10, and I can therefore calculate the height of each bar. The width of each bar is the distance between two adjacent quantiles, and of course I can calculate that as well. I have all the information I need, but I don't know how to plot a graph. How can, in matlab, plot I graph like the one in figure?
(it seems that I can plot histogram of different width, but with the hist function I cannot actually specify the height. With the bar function, however, I *can* specify the height but it seems I cannot change the width..)

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `rectangle`:

```
% sample data: set the start of each bar, the bottom (here 0), the width and the height

x = [0.5 0.6 0.9 1 1.2]; % start of bar
y = zeros(length(x),1);
dx = diff([x 1.8]); % width of bar
dy = [1 3 2 .5 .1];


figure, hold on
for ii=1:length(x)
    rectangle('position',[x(ii) y(ii) dx(ii) dy(ii)])
end
axis([0.5 2 0 4.1])

ylabel('Prob density')
xlabel('Time')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I have found my own solution, that i will put here after the mandatory 8 hours of waiting. After that I will choose your answer as accepted answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2116599 That works too, but note that from my experience `rectangle` is less likely to cause problems than `patch` with the way a rectangle is displayed

Comment: (sorry, I edit the comment because the code was totally messy. Thank you again)

Comment: The solution with rectangle it is indeed more elegant. However, when you call the function rectangle, you could as well write 
rectangle('Position', [x(ii) 0 dx(ii) dy(ii)]).

Comment: @user2116599 that's true :)